# smtplib repeating send unnecessarily

Tags: python, smtplib, imaplib

I'm running a script that will both fetch emails (imaplib) and will send alerts back to my personal email using smtplib. I am running it on my raspberry pi 24/7 and so when I am not at home I want to check that the program is still running fine.

Here are the functions:

```
def get_alert():
    global subject

    user = alert_email
    password = alert_email_password
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login(user, password)
    mail.list()
    mail.select('inbox')
    result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN')
    i = len(data[0].split())

    for x in range(i):
        latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
        result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
        subject = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['Subject'])))
        print(subject)
        return subject

    mail.logout()


def send_alert(subj, msg):

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(alert_email, alert_email_password)
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subj, msg)
    server.sendmail(from_addr=alert_email, to_addrs=personal_email, msg=message)
    server.quit()
```

Here's the loop:

```
while True:

    get_alert()

    if subject == 'check':       # check that program is still running

        send_alert(subj='still running', msg='still running')

    if subject == ...
```

So what happens is that it will get the 'check' email perfectly, and prints it out only once as it should. Yet every loop sends me 'still running' every time it runs despite the email being marked as read and having no more unread emails. Shouldn't subject be None if there are no unread emails?? I've tried manually setting subject to none and marking all emails as read after returning subject. Not sure what is happening, if you can help I greatly appreciate. this has been driving me nuts all day :/

Comment: `get_alert()` has a `return` statement in the `for` loop, so it only processes the first item in `data[0].split()`. It also never calls `mail.logout()` because of that, unless `i` is zero.

Comment: ah. moved the return statement out of the for loop and put log out above it. still getting the email every loop even though 'check' doesnt print out again. So what I dont get it why it is running the code in if subject == 'check' if subject is no longer 'check' :/

Comment: If there are no messages found, you don't change the value of the global variable `subject`.

Comment: don't use a global variable, use `subject = get_alert()`

Comment: If you move the `return` statement out of the loop, it returns the subject of the last message. What if there's a `check` message but it's not the last message?

Comment: oooh makes total sense now. and its working perfectly. thanks so much for your help @Barmar.  as for it not being the last message thats not a huge deal, bc i only get maybe 2-3 emails a day max. that i dont send to it. but will make a separate function just looking for 'check' instead of finding latest email to work around the small chance that happens